# AWS S3 .NET SDK: DeleteObjectsRequest return OK, but objects not deleted

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I have the following code to delete objects in a S3 "folder":

```
DeleteObjectsRequest req = new DeleteObjectsRequest();
req.BucketName = "mybucket/my foder 1/my folder 2";
req.AddKey("photo1.jpg", null);
req.AddKey("photo2.jpg", null);
DeleteObjectsResponse response = client.DeleteObjects(req);
```

response.HttpStatusCode is OK, and response.DeletedObjects.Count is 2. However, the actual objects are still there. Why?

This bucket had its versioning turned on then suspended before I created the folder to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out. It should be this:

```
DeleteObjectsRequest req = new DeleteObjectsRequest();
req.BucketName = "mybucket";
req.AddKey("my foder 1/my folder 2/photo1.jpg", null);
req.AddKey("my foder 1/my folder 2/photo2.jpg", null);
req.AddKey("my foder 1/my folder 2/", null);
DeleteObjectsResponse response = client.DeleteObjects(req);
```